# Harmonic Conjugate of $V(x,y) = \frac{1+x}{(1+x)^2 + g(y)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find the harmonic conjugate of $V(x,y) = \frac{1+x}{(1+x)^2 + g(y)}$ where $g(y)$ is a real function of a real variable to be determined. I need to find $u(x,y)$ s.t. $f(x,y) = u +iv$ is analytic.

However, the usual way of using the CR equations seems like it will be messy and i'm not sure how I would find what $g(y)$ should be. Does anyone know how to go about this exercise?

Answer (score 0):

The method of the Cauchy-Riemann equations seems to be not so complicated (If I have not made some computational errors).

$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}=-\frac{g^{\prime}(y)(1+x)}{((1+x)^2+g(y))^2}$$
Hence with $a$ a constant in $x$ (hence a function of $y$) we get

$$U(x,y)=a(y)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{g^{\prime}(y)}{(1+x)^2+g(y)}$$

Now 
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}=a^{\prime}(y)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{g^{\prime\prime}(y)((1+x)^2+g(y))-(g^{\prime}(y))^2}{(1+x)^2+g(y))^2}$$

and 
$$-\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}=\frac{(1+x)^2-g(y)}{(1+x)^2+g(y))^2}$$

Hence we get
$$2a^{\prime}(y)[(1+x)^2+g(y)]^2+(g^{\prime\prime}(y)((1+x)^2+g(y))-(g^{\prime}(y))^2)=2(1+x)^2-2g(y)$$

This is of the form :

$$2a^{\prime}(y)(1+x)^4+A(y)(1+x)^2+C(y)=0$$

As $(1+x)$ is not a constant, we must have $a^{\prime}(y)=0$.

The equation becomes:

$$(1+x)^2(2-g^{\prime\prime}(y))=g(y)g^{\prime\prime}(y)-(g^{\prime}(y))^2+2g(y)$$

We must have $g^{\prime\prime}(y)=2$, and $2g(y)+g(y)g^{\prime\prime}(y)-(g^{\prime}(y))^2=0$, and it is easy to finish the computation.

EDIT: Many thanks to Omran Kouba for pointing an error in the original proof.

Comment: Why must $g''(y)=2$?

Comment: Suppose not and fix $y$ such that $2-g^{\prime\prime}(y)$ is not $0$. You get that $1+x^2$ is a constant, a contradiction.

Comment: @Omran Kouba: Many thanks! I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

First, you need $V$ to be harmonic.  That $1+$ is a bit annoying: we may as well use a change of variables $X = 1+x$ (check that this doesn't affect $V$ being harmonic), so 
$$ V(X,y) = \dfrac{X}{X^2 + g(y)}$$
Now $$\dfrac{\partial^2 V }{\partial X^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2 V}{\partial y^2} = \dfrac{X}{(X^2 + g(y))^3} \left((2-g''(y)) X^2 - g(y) g''(y) + 2 g'(y)^2 - 6 g(y)\right) $$
We need $g''(y) = 2$, so $g(y) = y^2 + a y + b$ for some $y$, and you can check that this works iff $b = a^2/4$, where $a$ is arbitrary.  Thus

$$V(X,y) = \dfrac{X}{X^2 + (y + a/2)^2} $$
Can you take it from there?